# How to save integers from a .txt file into an array?

Tags: java

So i have an array int[] numbers = {1,2};
But i want the 1,2 to be removed and replaced with numbers from an txt file.
I can see the numbers from the files in the console with this method:

```
public String[] readLines(String filename) throws IOException {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
}

public static void testFileArrayProvider() throws IOException {
    algo1 fap = new algo1();
    String[] lines = fap
            .readLines("D:/Users/XXX/workspace/abc/src/abc1/Filename123");
    for (String line : lines) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

NOw i need to save them in the array. BUt how? xd
Thx guys

Comment: Could you give an example of your file contents? How are the numbers separated?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: number, next line, number, nextline. SO 1 number each line

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
   // In your case this is already populated
   String[] lines = new String[] {"123", "4567"};


    // Easier to work with lists first
    List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String line : lines) {
        results.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
    }

    // If you really want it to be int[] for some reason
    int[] finalResults = new int[results.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
        finalResults[i] = results.get(i);
    }

    // This is only to prove it worked
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalResults));
```

In Java-8, you can shorten it to

```
int[] finalResults = Arrays.stream(lines).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Comment: In java 8, `int[] finalResults = Arrays.stream(lines).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();`

Comment: @bradimus Even better. You should post it as a correct answer.

Comment: but where does it save the numbers intomy [int] numbers array? sry im a noob

Comment: @NiceMice In both examples, `finalResults` is an `int[]` containing your numbers. In the first example, it happens in the second `for-loop` where `finalResults[i] = results.get(i);`. In the second example, it occurs behind the scenes in the `toArray()` call.

Comment: hm, i copied and pasted your short solution into my main but it has a problem with "lines"--> Arrays.stream(lines). any ideas?

Comment: @NiceMice "has a problem" is rather difficult to diagnose. You do need to be using java 8 for it to work. If that is not the issue, you should probably post a new question with a link back to this one. Be sure to include the error message.

Comment: ok, so in my main there is int[] numbers= {}; do i need to change smt here? because i want the numbers from the.txt file saved there. not in the finalResults array.

Comment: You can replace `finalResults` with `numbers` (or any other name you like) in either solution. If you prefer, `numbers = finalResults;` will work too.

Comment: ok thx mate. 1 stewpid question: where do i post the code? in my main? or into the static void  testFileArrayProvider() method? i dont know what to change or what to delete after i paste your code in :/

Comment: This should replace your for loop